# Avoid UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database containing tables with Products and Salespeople.
Each Product is sold by a Salesperson, so there is a FK - PK link
between `Products.SalespersonId` and `Salespeople.Id`. Nothing unusual.

We can have a Sub-Salesperson who 'belongs' to a Salesperson,
so that table has a nullable `ParentSalespersonId` column
which is "pig's ear" FK'd back to `Salespeople.Id` PK.

Selecting Products sold by chosen Salesperson is trivial,
but *also* selecting Products sold by the Sub-Salespeople of the *chosen* Salesperson requires a `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Products
 INNER JOIN Salespeople ON Salespeople.Id = Products.SalespersonId
 WHERE Salespeople.Id = <some vale> -- products sold directly

UNION

SELECT *
  FROM Products
 INNER JOIN Salespeople AS Sub ON Sub.Id = Products.SalespersonId
 INNER JOIN Salespeople AS Parent
         ON Parent.Id = Sub.ParentSalespersonId
 WHERE Parent.Id = <some vale>-- products sold indirectly
```

Apart from being butt-ugly, that `UNION` causes a performance hit as two queries need to be executed instead of just one.

I've created many databases over the years, and written 100's of queries,
but I can't fathom this one...

How should the tables be re-structured in order achieve the relationships required, but removing the need for that ugly `UNION` and second `SELECT`?

Thanks

Comment: before avoiding `UNION` avoid `SELECT *`

Comment: Try the second query only, just add a condition for salesperson.id OR parent.id equal wanted value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Salespeople AS Sub ON Sub.Id = Products.SalespersonId
LEFT JOIN Salespeople AS Parent
       ON Parent.Id = Sub.ParentSalespersonId
WHERE Parent.Id = <some vale>
   OR Salespeople.Id = <some vale>
```

As Jodrell mentioned in comments, it's also advisable to explicitly select the columns you need, rather than `*`.

Comment: Thanks. That helped

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in just one query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products as P
    INNER JOIN Salespeople Sub ON Sub.Id = P.SalespersonId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Salespeople AS Parent ON Parent.Id = Sub.ParentSalespersonId
WHERE 
    Sub.Id = <some vale> -- products sold directly
    or Parent.Id = <some vale>-- products sold indirectly
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped

Answer (score 0):

erm,

```
SELECT
            * -- don't use SELECT *
    FROM
            [dbo].[Products] P
        LEFT JOIN
            [dbo].[Salespeople] I
                ON I.[Id] = P.[SalespersonId]
        LEFT JOIN
            [dbo].[Salespeople] S
                ON S.[Id] = P.[SalespersonId]
        LEFT JOIN
            [dbo].[Salespeople] P
                ON P.[Id] = S.[ParentSalespersonId]
    WHERE
            I.[Id] IS NOT NULL
        OR
            P.[Id] IS NOT NULL;
```